# Beamer Background defined by variable

Tags: beamer, packages, backgrounds

I have been trying for the past few days to create a new beamer custom style. I have manage to add an image to my background on the title page in the style (hard-coded) but I would like to add a variable option in the document where that image is specified. But it fails when I try.

```
Style document 
\mode<presentation>

% Requirement
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\AtBeginDocument{\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}}

\newcommand{\frontimage}{\includegraphics[width=\the\paperwidth, keepaspectratio]{Frontimage.JPG}} %my title page image hardcoded
\newcommand{\secimage}{\includegraphics[width=\the\paperwidth, keepaspectratio]{secimage.JPG}} %my section page image hardcoded
\useinnertheme{mytheme}
\useoutertheme{mytheme}
\usecolortheme{mytheme}

\defbeamertemplate*{background}{mytheme}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \ifnum\thepage>1\relax%
          %if base frame
          \fill[white,opacity=1] (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
     \else
          %if title page
          \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
          \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frontimage};
      \fi
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\mode<all>
```

And

```
Example Document
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Boring Title}

 \usetheme{mytheme}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
 \end{frame}

 \section{Introduction}
    \sectionframe
  \begin{frame}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Hopefully the MWE works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to pass the filename as an optional argument to the theme:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Boring Title}

\usepackage{filecontents} % <- just for creating this example
\begin{filecontents*}{beamerthememytheme.sty}
\mode<presentation>

% Requirement
\RequirePackage{tikz}
%\RequirePackage{graphicx}
%\RequirePackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Calibri}

%\AtBeginDocument{\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}}

\DeclareOptionBeamer{myimage}{\def\beamer@mytheme@myimage{#1}}
\ExecuteOptionsBeamer{myimage=example-image}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer


\newcommand{\frontimage}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, keepaspectratio]{\beamer@mytheme@myimage}} %my title page image hardcoded
%\useinnertheme{mytheme}
%\useoutertheme{mytheme}
%\usecolortheme{mytheme}

\defbeamertemplate*{background}{mytheme}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \ifnum\thepage>1\relax%
          %if base frame
          \fill[white,opacity=1] (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
     \else
          %if title page
          \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
          \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frontimage};
      \fi
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\mode<all>
\end{filecontents*}

\usetheme[
    myimage=example-image-duck
]{mytheme}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
%  \sectionframe
\begin{frame}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, What is the purpose of the \usepackage{filecontents}  and the begin{filecontents} parts?

Comment: @Simon I was just lazy and did not want to manually create the `.sty` file. In your real project you don't need it

Comment: And in the \usetheme[%insert duck image here]{mytheme} is it only the file name or the whole \includegraphics{...] I must us?

Comment: @Simon Just the file name, like in my example if you uncomment `myimage=example-image-duck`

Comment: Thank you, it works in my main file, not that the duck isn't beautifull ;) but I had difficulty because i removed the myimage= from the \usetheme[...]{...} code.